# Multiple User Voice Chat in the Browser [JavaScript and NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to add a voice chat for multiple users (like a Discord voice channel), for my Discord clone project.

After too long, I got it to haphazardly work with 2 people max using PeerJS. I'd like to extend this to more than 3 people. I have done research and I have found not much help for this.

I am using **socket.io**, an **express.js** API - https://github.com/theADAMJR/discord-voice-chat.

How would you **add multiple user voice chat** in a NodeJS web application?

Comment: We don't recommend libraries on Stack Overflow.  One of the valid reasons to close a question is _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._